# What does it mean "Break Ya Neck" and "Protect Ya Neck"

Tags: meaning-in-context

They both are expressions that name rappers songs.

1. [Protect Ya Neck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpQmFfdYFzY)
2. [Break Ya Neck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnL3rfBBrYE)

I have intuitions, but what exactly do they mean?

Comment: I don't know what they mean and have no interest in listening to the songs. I have intuition also. Maybe you could use a search engine and look up the phrases, or better yet, look up the song lyrics. Then if you have trouble understanding what they mean in context, ask a more specific question...

Comment: This is not usefully answerable.  They mean "Protect your neck" and figuratively "protect your vulnerable area from deadly attack".  But what they mean in the context of some unmentioned song is interpretation and beyond the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rap exegesis site [Rap Genius](http://genius.com/1451797/Wu-tang-clan-protect-ya-neck/Yo-you-best-protect-ya-neck), the title phrase of Wu-Tang Clan's "Protect Ya Neck" in context should be taken as a threat to the person/party the song is addressed to, with the implication that the rapper or someone is about to try to chop off the addressee's head.  It means something like "en garde" or "put your dukes up".

Meanwhile, [it proposes here](http://genius.com/Busta-rhymes-break-ya-neck-lyrics/) that in Busta Rhymes' "Break Ya Neck", the titular phrase is an exhortation to the listener to nod vigorously along with the rap very hard -- it's a hyperbole, to bounce one's head with the beat so hard as to break one's neck.

Answer (score 0):

*Ya* is a *slang* term. I've often heard *ya* where they want to use *your*. The commonest, though offensive, is 'f*** ya a**!' means 'f*** your a**!'

I listened to those song and it's full of slang words it seems. This *backs* my answer!

Protect Ya Neck and Break Ya Neck, in that sense, could mean 'Protect your neck' and 'Break your neck'. And yes, listen to the video *Break Ya Neck*, the singer sings *Break your f*** neck!*

The [OnlineSlangDictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/ya) defines *your* as **one of the** meanings of the slang term *ya*.